# How to substract lines from two files with nodepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have two files (A and B) and I want to substract the lines of B from A.

That is, given these files:

FileA:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

and FileB:

```
line2
line4
```

the result would be:

```
line1
line3
```

The lines are separated accross the file, they are not in line with each other.

How can I do this witn notepad++?

Comment: Do they share certain attributes?

Comment: Nope they dont.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 2 files (one with 14 mil and the other with 1 mil lines) and you want to delete those 1 mil lines in the 14 mil lines file?

Comment: That is not a job for Npp, you'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Yes @cincout  I dont know anything about writing scripts

Comment: Does the lines at the `14 million lines` file can be reapeated ? Or are they unique?

Comment: They can be repeated yes

Comment: Then you could try with the solution I posted that joins both files with some sort of separator + replace with regexp. Just let me know.

Comment: @JoleMCFactionsandmore Are you on Mac or PC?

Comment: PC windows 10 I'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by manually merging both files and then apply some regexp.

Imagine file "A" with these lines:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vwx
```

and to-be-substracted file "B" with these lines:

```
abc
mno
vwx
```

Merge them under just one file and separe the contents with at least 20 `@`, like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vwx

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

abc
mno
vwx
```

Now apply this regexp:

Search: `^([^\n\r]+)\R(?=[\s\S]+^@{20,}$[\s\S]*^\1$)`

Replace by `(nothing)`

Search method: `regular expression`

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>

The result will be:

```
def
ghi
jkl
pqr
stu

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

abc
mno
vwx
```

Now simply remove the content of the second file.

**Important:**

In order for this to work, you need a 'unique' separator that cannot be found on any of the two files. I used `@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@` for this purpose, but if you feel that this can be found elsewhere, the solution should be changed to use some other separator (for both merging the files and using the regular expression)